# Как отсылать email из локального сервера?

Tags: php, email, mandrill

Нужно сделать отправку email сообщения через сервис Mandrill.

Сделал пример по [гайду,](https://habrahabr.ru/post/256055/) но письмо не отсылается!

Подозреваю что это из за того, что я не зарегистрировал SPF и DKIM, но работаю на локальном сервере, и не знаю как зарегистрировать DNS.

**Возможно ли отсылать email из локального сервера ?**

**скрипт:**

```
<?php

require_once ('mandrill-api/src/Mandrill.php');

$mail = new Mandrill('5l-qONinNOuZ8a0iZg_Hrg');

/* Блок динамического контента */
$tpl_con = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'my-label',
        'content' => '<h2>Моя рассылка</h2>'
    )
);

$data = array(
    'html' => 'It is html text',
    'text' => 'It is simple text',
    'subject' => 'My mess',
    'from_email' => 'friend@example.com',
    'from_name' => 'Michael',
    'to' => array(      
        array(
            'email' => 'vitaliyprokopovoak@gmail.com',
            'name' => 'Lucas',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
    ),
    'global_merge_vars' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'NAME',
            'content' => 'Lucas'
        )
    ),
    'merge_vars' => array(
        array(
            'rcpt' => 'vitaliyprokopovoak@gmail.com',
            'vars' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'NAME',
                    'content' => 'Lucas'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'subaccount' => 'prokopov-sub'
);

try {
    /* Отправка обычного письма */
    $result = $mail->messages->send($data);
    print_r($result);
} catch(Mandrill_Error $error) {
    echo 'Error: ' . get_class($error) . ' - ' . $error->getMessage();
}
```

результат:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => vitaliyprokopovoak@gmail.com
>   [status] => rejected [_id] => 8b597ab4d9b04b49ab6366e232831306
>   [reject_reason] => unsigned ) )

Comment: скрипты покажи которыми отсылаешь?

Comment: @Naumov, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: У тебя письма заварачивають либо в спам либо на адресс во фроме `friend@example.com` измени на существующий который можешь проверить

Comment: @Naumov, изменил,  раньше ничего не изменялось, но сейчас stаus => queued, и письма так и не приходят!

Comment: @Naumov, я так понял, оно их в очередь поставило, но ждал минут 10 - так ничего и не пришло!

Comment: @Mabe_V а зачем вам собственно стороним сервисом пользоваться?

Comment: @Naumov, задание стоит сделать через этот сервис :(

Comment: а возможно посмотреть статус сервера на сервисе он вообще запущен?